# Javascript SVG Animation on iPhone CPU usage

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, svg, cpu

I have a loop running in a game I've been working on that basically animates a circular timer. The loop is using requestAnimationFrame, the circle is build with an svg, and I'm set attributing the stroke-dashoffset every other frame (30fps). The CPU usage is sitting at ~45% with 3 different attributes being updated in the loop. When I disable all of them it jumps down to ~3% (no surprise). The question is why when I comment out 2 of the them, the CPU still sits at ~45%. Why is there no difference between animating 1 and 3 elements on CPU usage? Does ~45% sound high? (I'm running the game on an iphone 6plus and the timer svg is pretty small on the screen, if that makes a difference).

Comment: Most if not all UAs these days process updates asynchronously. They aggregate all changes in a time window and then do 1 screen refresh with all of them in.

Answer (score 1):

45 % is not enormous, 90 % *should* be a problem. SVG drawings doesn't need lot of performances, and you're displaying it on a small screen, that reduces the CPU usage because of the pixel matrix of each SVG is small and the work to do on them is small too (I hope I'm clear).

Animating 1 or 3 SVG elements doesn't impact performances a lot because, as I said, they are some small elements that doesn't need lot of performances to be animated. I think the CPU usage is due to your JS script and not to the SVG drawing (after all displaying 1 or 3 elements doesn't impact performances !)